# How to display my plugin view at right side of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

My Plugin is by default display on middle bottom of Eclipse, how could I make it to display at right side of Eclipse?
My plugin.xml looks like below, any hints will be more than welcome!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="My Plugin"
            id="com.xx.plugin">
      </category>

      <view
            name="XX my plugin View"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="com.xx.plugin"
            class="com.xx.MyPluginView"
            id="com.xx.MyPluginView">
      </view>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the `view` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point for this. You have to do it for each perspective you want to customize.

Something like the following should show the view in the same stack as the outline view at the right in the Java Perspective.

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
     <view
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline"
           visible="true"
           id="com.xx.MyPluginView"
           relationship="stack">
     </view>
```

Note: You may have to reset the perspective to get the extension picked up.